# Issue with loading jquery twice with requirejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

Jquery is loaded fine, but when I look at the network tab I see that it is loaded again which is what im trying to prevent. The initial load of jquery is a script tag at the top level of the application. I used this code below after looking at the documentation hoping that I would define jquery as a module if it already existed. However I ended up having it still being loaded twice.

```
!function (window) {
    requirejs.config({
        baseUrl: basePath + "/testing/kendo_scripts",
    });

    if (typeof jQuery === 'function') {
        console.log(jQuery);
        console.log("In jquery check");
        define('jquery', function () { return jQuery; });
    }
```

A picture of the second load:
[image: Loaded again]

Any suggestions on how I can prevent this?

Comment: Do you have the jQuery script tag already in the page?

Comment: yea, and in the post you linked me to, i also tried that solution however im still loading jquery for some reason

Comment: Nvm figured it out, the folder I was requiring had files that depended on jquery.min rather than jquery.

Comment: And jquery min isn't jquery?